# Parse time_period expression with Boost::Spirit

Tags: c++, parsing, boost, boost-spirit, boost-date-time

I need to parse following EBNF expression with Boost::Spirit.

```
period ::= date_part [time_part] , date_part [time_part]
time_part ::= hours:minutes[:seconds]
date_part ::= day.month.year
```

For example, `10.06.2014 10:00:15, 11.07.2014`. I made my grammar in two ways, but can't exactly get working example.

1) First attempt

```
    struct Parser: grammar<std::string::const_iterator, space_type>
    {
        Parser(): Parser::base_type(datetime_)
        {
            using boost::spirit::int_;

            using boost::spirit::qi::_1;
            using boost::spirit::qi::_2;

            using boost::spirit::qi::_val;

            datetime_ =
                (date_ >> time_)
                [
                  _val =
                    phoenix::construct<ptime>
                    (
                      date(_1[2]), _1[1], _1[0]),
                hours(_2[0]) + minutes(_2[1]) + seconds[_2[0]]
                    )
                  |
                  _val =
                    phoenix::construct<ptime>
                    (
                      date(_1[2]), _1[1], _1[0]),
                seconds(0)
                    )
                ];

            date_ %= int_ % '.';
            time_ %= int_ % ':';

            BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG_NODE(datetime_);
            BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG_NODE(date_);
            BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG_NODE(time_);
        }

        rule<std::string::const_iterator, std::vector<int>(), space_type> date_, time_;
        rule<std::string::const_iterator, ptime(), space_type> datetime_;
    }

    Parser parser;
    std::string strTest("10.06.2014 10:00:15, 11.07.2014");

    std::string::const_iterator it_begin(strTest.begin());
    std::string::const_iterator it_end(strTest.end());

    bool result = phrase_parse(it_begin, it_end, parser, space);
```

Errors:

`/media/Data/Projects/Qt/Planner/parser.h:108: ошибка: no matching function for call to 'boost::gregorian::date::date(boost::phoenix::detail::make_index_composite<boost::phoenix::actor<boost::spirit::argument<0> >, int>::type)'`

And so on. I can't cast `boost::spirit::argument<0>` to `int` or `date::years_type`. I tryed `date((int)_1[2]), (int)_1[1], (int)_1[0]))` and `dynamic_cast<int>(_1[2])`, but with no success (.

2) Second attempt

```
    struct Parser: grammar<std::string::const_itearator, space_type>
    {
        Parser(ConditionTree& a_lTree):
            Parser::base_type(time_period_),
            m_lTree(a_lTree)
        {
            using boost::spirit::int_;

            using boost::spirit::qi::_1;
            using boost::spirit::qi::_2;
            using boost::spirit::qi::_3;
            using boost::spirit::qi::_4;
            using boost::spirit::qi::_5;
            using boost::spirit::qi::_val;

            time_period_ = ( datetime_ > ',' > datetime_ ) [ _val = phoenix::construct<time_period>((int)_1, (int)_3) ];

            datetime_ = (date_ >> time_duration_) [ _val = phoenix::construct<ptime>((int)_1, (int)_2) | _val = phoenix::construct<ptime>((int)_1, seconds(0)) ] ;

            date_ = (int_ > '.' > int_ > '.' > int_) [ _val = phoenix::construct<date>((int)_5, (int)_3, (int)_1) ];

            time_duration_ = (int_ > ':' > int_ > ':' > int_) [ _val = phoenix::construct<time_duration>((int)_1, (int)_3, (int)_5, 0)];

            BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG_NODE(time_period_);
            BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG_NODE(datetime_);
            BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG_NODE(date_);
            BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG_NODE(time_duration_);

        }

        rule<std::string::const_itarator, time_period(), space_type> time_period_;
        rule<std::string::const_itarator, ptime(), space_type> datetime_;
        rule<std::string::const_itarator, date(), space_type> date_;
        rule<std::string::const_itarator, time_duration(), space_type> time_duration_;

        ConditionTree& m_lTree;
    };
```

Error:

`/media/Data/Projects/Qt/Planner/parser.h:114: ошибка: invalid cast from type 'const _1_type {aka const boost::phoenix::actor<boost::spirit::argument<0> >}' to type 'int'`...

Why I can't cast boost::spirit::argument<0> to int????

Comment: Try to remove focus from semantic actions http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8259440/boost-spirit-semantic-actions-are-evil

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Better question, why would you be able to cast a placeholder type to a specific primitive type?

The place holder is a *lazy actor* only, so you should use Phoenix `cast_` to cast it, if at all (*hint*: this should not be necessary): **[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/44acc4b8be4d0384)**

Output

```
<period_>
<try>10.06.2014 10:00:15,</try>
<date_>
    <try>10.06.2014 10:00:15,</try>
    <success> 10:00:15, 11.07.201</success>
    <attributes>[[10, 6, 2014]]</attributes>
</date_>
<time_>
    <try> 10:00:15, 11.07.201</try>
    <success>, 11.07.2014</success>
    <attributes>[[10, 0, 15]]</attributes>
</time_>
<date_>
    <try> 11.07.2014</try>
    <success></success>
    <attributes>[[11, 7, 2014]]</attributes>
</date_>
<time_>
    <try></try>
    <fail/>
</time_>
<success></success>
<attributes>[[[[10, 6, 2014], [10, 0, 15]], [[11, 7, 2014], [empty]]]]</attributes>
</period_>
Parse success
```

#### Full Sample

```
#define BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG
#include <boost/fusion/adapted/struct.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/phoenix.hpp>

namespace qi  = boost::spirit::qi;
namespace phx = boost::phoenix;

namespace Ast {
    using boost::optional;
    struct date { unsigned day, month, year; };
    struct time { unsigned hours, minutes, seconds; };
    struct date_time { date date_part; optional<time> time_part; };

    struct period { date_time start, end; };
}

BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(Ast::date, (unsigned,day)(unsigned,month)(unsigned,year))
BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(Ast::time, (unsigned,hours)(unsigned,minutes)(unsigned,seconds))
BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(Ast::date_time, (Ast::date,date_part)(Ast::optional<Ast::time>, time_part))
BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(Ast::period, (Ast::date_time,start)(Ast::date_time,end))

template <typename Iterator>
struct Parser : qi::grammar<Iterator, Ast::period(), qi::space_type>
{
    int test;
    Parser() : Parser::base_type(period_)
    {
        using namespace qi;

        static const int_parser<unsigned, 10, 2, 2> _2digit = {};
        static const int_parser<unsigned, 10, 4, 4> _4digit = {};

        time_      = _2digit >> ":" >> _2digit >> ":" >> _2digit;
        date_      = _2digit >> "." >> _2digit >> "." >> _4digit;
        date_time_ = date_ >> -time_;
        period_    = date_time_ >> "," >> date_time_;

        BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG_NODES((period_)(time_)(date_))
    }

  private:
    qi::rule<Iterator, Ast::period(),    qi::space_type> period_;
    qi::rule<Iterator, Ast::date(),      qi::space_type> date_;
    qi::rule<Iterator, Ast::time(),      qi::space_type> time_;
    qi::rule<Iterator, Ast::date_time(), qi::space_type> date_time_;
};


int main()
{
    using It = std::string::const_iterator;

    Parser<It> parser;
    std::string input("10.06.2014 10:00:15, 11.07.2014");

    It f(input.begin()), l(input.end());

    Ast::period parsed;
    bool ok = qi::phrase_parse(f, l, parser, qi::space, parsed);

    if (ok)
    {
        std::cout << "Parse success\n";
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "Parse failed\n";
    }

    if (f!=l)
        std::cout << "Remaining unparsed input: '" << std::string(f,l) << "'\n";
}
```

Comment: You mean, optional members? Sure. Updating... **Updated** answer. @adil

Comment: Sorry, I have deleted comment. So, I return. Yes, you are right, I told about optional members. `period ::= date_part [time_part] , date_part [time_part]
time_part ::= hours:minutes[:seconds]`

Comment: Interestingly, by reposting that comment, the answer predates it by 16 hours :). If you want seconds optional, make it e.g. `time_ = _2digit >> ":" >> _2digit >> (":" >> _2digit | attr(0u));` (which takes `00` for seconds if unspecified)

Comment: Thanks a lot! It works! Thanks for boost::optional, it's very helpful. I will add EBNF to the source question.